# Speeding up cross-reference filtering in Pandas DB

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I am working with a very large donation database of data with relevant columns for donation ID, conduit ID, amount, for example:

```
  TRANSACTION_ID BACK_REFERENCE_TRAN_ID_NUMBER  CONTRIBUTION_AMOUNT
0    VR0P4H2SEZ1                             0                  100
1    VR0P4H3X770                             0                 2700
2    VR0P4GY6QV1                             0                  500
3    VR0P4H3X720                             0                 1700
4    VR0P4GYHHA0                  VR0P4GYHHA0E                  200
```

What I need to do is to identify all of the rows where the TRANSACTION_ID corresponds to any BACK_REFERENCE_TRAN_ID_NUMBER. My current code, albeit a little clumsy, is:

```
is_from_conduit = df[df.BACK_REFERENCE_TRAN_ID_NUMBER != "0"].BACK_REFERENCE_TRAN_ID_NUMBER.tolist()
df['CONDUIT_FOR_OTHER_DONATION'] = 0
for row in df.index:
    if df['TRANSACTION_ID'][row] in is_from_conduit:
        df['CONDUIT_FOR_OTHER_DONATION'][row] = 1
    else:
        df['CONDUIT_FOR_OTHER_DONATION'][row] = 0
```

However, on very large data sets with a large number of conduit donations, this takes for ever. I know there must be a simpler way, but clearly I can't come up with how to phrase this to find out what that may be.

Comment: Is there a reason for the extra `'E'` at the end of `df.iloc[4, 1]`?

Comment: I edit a bit to make the copy/pasting easier. It shouldn't change what you wrote. However, I don't get what you mean. Can you show your expected output ? Here your column `CONDUIT_FOR_OTHER_DONATION` only has `0`s

Comment: 4)  VR0P4GYHHA0   <>  VR0P4GYHHA0E

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html). It is a vectorized operation that checks if each element of the Series is in a supplied iterable.

```
df['CONDUIT_FOR_OTHER_DONATION'] = df['TRANSACTION_ID'].isin(df['BACK_REFERENCE_TRAN_ID_NUMBER'].unique())
```

As @root mentioned if you prefer `0`/`1` (as in your example) instead of `True`/`False`, you can cast to `int`:

```
df['CONDUIT_FOR_OTHER_DONATION'] = df['TRANSACTION_ID'].isin(df['BACK_REFERENCE_TRAN_ID_NUMBER'].unique()).astype(int)
```

Comment: I think you should add a `.astype(int)` since `isin` return booleans and it looks like the example code gives 0/1 values.

Comment: It doesn't make any long term difference between returning T/F or 1/0, but this works out perfectly either way, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a NumPy based approach using [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) -

```
vals = np.in1d(df.TRANSACTION_ID,df.BACK_REFERENCE_TRAN_ID_NUMBER).astype(int)
df['CONDUIT_FOR_OTHER_DONATION'] = vals
```

Comment: np.in1D() seems to give membership -- how would you get position or index value.

Comment: @Merlin I am not sure if we need membership or position as it gets the entire output column in one go and we are just assigning a new column and putting values `vals` in it in the existing dataframe. or did I miss something there?

Comment: The function gives membership. I am wondering if you can get position or index. The docs > [0,2,0] is membership. but what is the index of the elements.  The second '0' has index 5. How could I get that.

Comment: @Merlin Ah! Assuming I got your question, using `np.where(np.in1d(..))`? Oh, if you meant to correspond which elems came from which, we can use `np.searchsorted`. Back to the question though, I am assuming OP is looking to get `0` or `1` in the output column as suggested by the  code posted by OP.

Comment: just checked np.searchsorted would give element position in sorted "list", not index of original "list"

Comment: @Merlin We need to use optional arg with it : `sorter=first_input.argsort()`.